# My PopupWindow keeps stealing my EditText's focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup, focus

I have a simple "command dialog" that's a PopupWindow containing an EditText and a couple of buttons.  I want the following behavior:

- Touching outside the popup window dismisses it
- When the popup appears, the EditText should grab (and keep) the focus

My EditText looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/send_cmd_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:hint="@string/send_cmd_hint"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:minEms="100"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

The popup construction looks like this:

```
    val popup = PopupWindow(view)
    popup.isOutsideTouchable = true
    popup.isTouchable = true
    popup.isFocusable = true
    popup.contentView = view

    // This bizarre hack allows outside touching to dismiss it.
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

    sendButton.setOnClickListener {
        sendCommand()
        popup.dismiss()
    }

    if (A.isHardwareKeyboardAvailable()) {
        // This only fires for the hardware keyboard.
        editText.setOnKeyListener { _, code, event -> handleKey(code, event) }
    } else {
        setImeListener()
    }

    editText.requestFocus()
```

There seems to be a race condition occurring.  I've got a hardware keyboard attached, and there are two ways to open the popup:

1. I can hit the Enter key, which the Activity notices, and then it calls the function to construct and show the popup.
2. I can press a button in my UI, which calls the same function.

Whenever I open the popup by pressing the button, the EditText gets the focus and everyone is happy.

Whenever I open the popup by pressing the Enter key on my hardware keyboard, the EditText gets the focus briefly, and then becomes unfocused.  I suspect without proof that the PopupWindow is stealing the focus.

I need the popup to be focusable -- otherwise the keypresses simply go to the Activity, where it becomes difficult to route them back to the EditText.

I also need the popup to be outsideTouchable, so it will dismiss when you touch outside it.

I've tried setting isTouchable to false, but it seems to have no effect either way.

I've tried various oddball suggestions I've found related to this issue, such as calling popup.update() and so on.  Nothing has solved the problem.

Again, this *only* happens when I have opened the popup by hitting the Enter key.  The only difference I can see is that perhaps the Activity gets the focus temporarily before I create the popup, whereas if I press the UI button to open the popup, the Activity never gets the keyboard focus.  Not sure, though.

The only thing that *has* worked for me is to set a timer:

```
    android.os.Handler().postDelayed({ editText.requestFocus() }, 250)
```

This does the trick, but is obviously lame and fragile.

Any idea how to prevent my popup from stealing the focus from an EditText inside it?

Answer (score -1):

Find the solution

```
final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(vbl.getMainLayout());
....
popUp.setFocusable(true);
popUp.update();
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this solves my problem.  My question specifically says I tried popup.update() and it doesn't work.  It's already focusable.